# Node package.json "bin" value, command not working

Tags: json, node.js, npm, package.json

I used nodejs on my vserver to make a tiny script to manage users in a db.

In package.json I added the "bin" and set it to my script. My attempt was to make a command available on the whole server so I dont need to go to the directory where the script lies and write "node usermanager.js".

I used npm link and it seemed to work fine:

```
/home/sl4yer/bin/cl9wnhook -> /home/sl4yer/lib/node_modules/cl9wnhook_usermanager/usermanager.js
/home/sl4yer/lib/node_modules/cl9wnhook_usermanager -> /home/sl4yer/cl9wnHook/usermanager
```

package.json btw is:

```
{
  "name": "cl9wnhook_usermanager",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "User manager for cl9wnHook",
  "main": "usermanager.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "bin": {
    "cl9wnhook": "./usermanager.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "commander": "^2.9.0",
    "js-sha512": "^0.2.2",
    "readline-sync": "^1.4.5"
  }
}
```

so using the command "cl9wnhook" should work.

But when I call it, I get:

```
[sl4yer@lynx usermanager]$ cl9wnhook
: No such file or directory
```

Any idea?

Comment: [This](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin) could help u.

Comment: isnt that exactly what i do?]

Comment: is `~/bin/cl9wnhook` works?

Comment: Nope :( same error. Seems like the command is registered but the file is not being found :(

Comment: Did u get any solution? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 15):

```
sudo npm link
```

I did it, and successfully.

Comment: Thanks! You probably don't need to use `sudo`.

Comment: This works, and I also didn't need to use the sudo.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

on the top of your usermanager.js file. It should work.

Comment: Yep, worked after adding to typescript file

Answer (score 3):

your `bin` in your `package.json` like this:

```
{
"bin": {
    "app": "bin/app"
  },
}
```

but first in your `app` file you should add at the top this `#!/usr/bin/env node`

**Note**

[This will help you](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#bin)

Answer (score 1):

Pack the package

```
npm pack
```

Then install it globally to run it from any folder.

```
npm install --global <package_file>.tgz
```

Answer (score 0):

Really things can mess up from time to time when working with NPM or Yarn. In these cases first do a complete clean install.

```sh
rm -rf ./node_modules
```

```sh
yarn install
npm install
```

If that doesn't solve your problem then check the `bin` property in `package.json`, if it is mapping to the cli file correctly?

You can check what is packed by running `yarn pack`.

Answer (score 0):

For a more complete answer in relation to using `"bin"` with `npm link` ;

- The `package.json` of the linked library needs to include a `"bin"` property which points to the `.js` file you wish to use, most likely `index.js`. So `"bin": { "my-package-name": "lib/index.js" }`
- The `.js` file needs to have `#!/usr/bin/env node` on the first line.
- The `.js` file needs to have correct permissions to execute `sudo chmod +x lib/index.js`
- To allow your package to be linked, you need to run `npm link` in the root directory of the package, which includes the `package.json` containing the name of the package, i.e. `my-package-name`
- To link that package to another project, you need to run `npm link my-package-name` in the root directory of that project, which contains its own `package.json`
- To check the link was successful, you need to run `npm list`, which should show your package linked in the current projects